# unable to connect to Mailchimp services using java wrapper

Tags: java

I am using Java wrapper of mailchimp API for converting to inline CSS.
I downloaded the java wrapper and tried with method inlineCss();
I register with Mailchimp and got the Api key.

API Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1

I am getting the below exception while calling the ping(apiKey) method.
Could you please provide me the solution to resolve this problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.nwire.mailchimp.MailChimpServiceException: Failed to read servers response: api.mailchimp.com
      at com.nwire.mailchimp.MailChimpServiceFactory$ClientFactory$1.invoke(MailChimpServiceFactory.java:190)
      at $Proxy0.ping(Unknown Source)
      at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.InlineTest.initialize(InlineTest.java:44)
      at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.InlineTest.run(InlineTest.java:36)
      at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.InlineTest.main(InlineTest.java:23)
```

Below is the code I am using for connecting to Mailchimp.

```
public void initialize() {
                                mcServices = MailChimpServiceFactory.getMailChimpServices();
                                final String ping = mcServices.ping(apiKey);
                                if (IMailChimpServices.PING_SUCCESS.equals(ping)) {
                                                logger.error("MailChimp connection pinged successfully");
                                } else {
                                                logger.error("Failed to ping MailChimp, response: " + ping);
                                }
                }
```

Regards,
Nagesh.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution

To support Mailchimp datacenter mapping scheme. 
Access the correct datacenter 
*  http://.api.mailchimp.com/1.2/
*  replace  with position after dash in Our Api key eg.us1 ,uk2 etc.

Check your Url present in MailChimpServiceFactory class of Java-warapper

by default Java wrapper provides

config.setServerURL(new URL("http://api.mailchimp.com/1.2/"))
changed above url to "http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.2/"

for more information visit this link  http://www.mailchimp.com/api/1.2/